# Is it possible to win a cricket match by 0 wickets?

Tags: rules, cricket

Suppose we have an ODI match between Team A and Team B. Team B batted first and scored 300 / 6 in 50 overs. After 49.5 overs, Team A reaches 300 / 9. Player X, who is on strike, is on 98. He wants to complete his century. In the following situation, what happens:

- A legal ball is bowled, and the the batsman hits it straight to a fielder at long on.
- Both the batsmen start running and complete a run.
- Player X turns back for another run.
- His partner is busy celebrating their win and does not turn back.
- The fielder throws the ball towards the bowler's end.
- Player X, seeing that his partner is not turning back, tries to return back.
- It's a direct hit, and Player X is out.

The score is now 301 / 10, and Team A has won, but by how many wickets? 0?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The match is over as soon as the batsmen complete their first run, so the last five points (from "Player X turns back for another run") are irrelevant. Quoting specifically [Law 21.6 Winning hit or extras](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-21-the-result/):

> As soon as a result is reached [...] the match is at an end. Nothing that happens thereafter [...] shall be regarded as part of it.

The result would be that Team A scored 301/9 and won by one wicket.

Comment: I'd more be asking "why was there a fielder at long on?". With one run to win, the opposition captain should have brought everyone in to save the single, so your hit would have gone for four and you would have got your century...

Answer (score 3):

Team A has won by 1 wicket. The reason is that once a team has scored enough runs to constitute a result, nothing that happens afterwards is relevant. This is stated in [Law 21, Section 6a](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-21-the-result/).

In your scenario, once the batsmen have completed the first run, the game is over and the subsequent run-out is irrelevant.

The only exception to this law is stated in section 6c, which deals with a boundary. In your scenario, the batsman needed to hit a boundary, and not complete a run before the ball crosses the rope, to receive 4 or 6 runs and make his century.

Answer (score 1):

The match ends as soon as the first run is scored.

I remember one incident in this context, it was a match IND vs SL where the score was level while Virender Sehwag was on 99*. He missed a century even though he hit a over-boundary as the bowler bowled a no-ball.

http://www.espncricinfo.com/sl-tri2010/content/story/472752.html